# Cómo pasarle una función a un get en Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nodejs

Estoy siguiendo los ejemplos de un libro sobre [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) y tengo dos fragmentos de código idénticos, uno para un `set` y el otro para un `get`. Como me parece que esto viola el principio [**DRY**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas), intenté reescribir el código en una función, pero no *funcionó*.

Este es el código que funciona, repetido, en un esquema para Usuarios en [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose):

```
  var UserSchema = new Schema({
    // otros campos... 
    website: {
      type: String,
      get: function(url) {
        if(!url) {
          return url
        } else {
          if (url.indexOf('http://') !== 0 && url.indexOf('https://') !== 0) {
            url = 'http://' + url;
          }
          return url;
        }
      },  // ./get
      set: function(url){
        if(!url){
          return url;
        } else {
          if (url.indexOf('http://') !== 0 && url.indexOf('https://') !== 0){
            url = 'http://' + url;
          } 
          return url;
        }
      }   // ./set  
    }     // ./website
  }       // ./UserSchema
```

> Entiendo que si uso el `get` ya no necesitaría el `set`, pero la comprensión y resolución del problema es parte de mi proceso de aprendizaje.

Trato de evitar la repetición del código, haciendo una función que haga este trabajo:

```
  function dameURI(url) {
    if(!url) {
      return url
    } else {
      if (url.indexOf('http://') !== 0 && url.indexOf('https://') !== 0) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
      }
      return url;
    }
  }
```

Y reemplazo la función anónima de `get` por esta función nueva:

```
// ...
website: {
  // ...
  get: dameURI(url),
  set: function(url) {
    // la función anómina que si funciona
  }
}
```

Al ejecutar el servidor, [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) se queja porque dice que `url` no está definida:

```
 $  node server
/la/ruta/a/mi/proyecto/app/models/user.server.model.js:34
      get: dameURI(url),
                   ^

ReferenceError: url is not defined
```

También intenté usar esta forma (que no sé como se llama):

```
var dameURI = function(url) {
  // ...
}
```

con idénticos resultados negativos.

### Pregunta

¿Cómo puedo pasar el contenido del campo `website` a mi función `dameURI` tanto en el `get` como en el `set` para no tener código repetido?

**Extra points**: ¿Cuál es mi error?

Comment: Tu error es que estás llamando a la función. Debería ser `website : { get : dameUri, set : dameUri }`

Comment: Gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, ¿podrías crear una respuesta para que la marque como aceptada? Sería genial si puedes elaborar un poco más sobre el error que estoy cometiendo. Gracias.

Comment: Hecho! =) Por curiosidad, para qué necesitas en el objeto dos propiedades distintas si almacenan la misma función?

Comment: Gracias. En realidad solo se requiere una, cierto. Las instrucciones del libro dicen que reemplace `set` por `get` pero al intentar usar la función, no funcionó y no entendía por qué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Trato de evitar la repetición del código, haciendo una función que
>   haga este trabajo"

```
  function dameURI(url) {
    if(!url) {
      return url
    } else {
      if (url.indexOf('http://') !== 0 && url.indexOf('https://') !== 0) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
      }
      return url;
    }
  }
```

> "Y reemplazo la función anónima de get por esta función nueva:"

```
website: {
  // ...
  get: dameURI(url),
  set: function(url) {
    // la función anómina que si funciona
  }
}
```

El error que obtienes es que la variable url no está definida, pero no debe estar deinida en tu caso, ya que es el parámetro que recibe dicha función. Lo que necesitas no es el contenido que de vuelva la función dameUri, sino almacenar dicha función, en resumen, básicamente es un objeto que almacene dichas funciones:

```js
const fn = ()=> console.log('HelloWorld');

const obj = {
  get : fn,
  set : fn
}

obj.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose tiene entre sus middelwares un método [pre()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/middleware.html) que puedes utilizar para lo que necesitas.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  // válidas tu URI aquí 
  next()
})
```